# remove \xa0 and amend just the numbers

Tags: python, arrays

I have written a program to extract a table using bs4 and part of the program contains extracting the texts from the cell and amend it to an array
I have received the following output and i want to remove all the \xa0
and I also want to save just the number in the final array (here stmat), for example, I want just "74" from "74°F"
can I get the answers for the above 2 question's
below is just the for loop for ammending

```
    for row in stat_table.find_all('tr') :
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            print(cell.text)
            stmat.append(cell.text)
            count = count + 1
            m = m+1
            print(count)        
     print(stmat)
     n = count/10
```

I've got the following output for amended matrix

```
['8:30 PM', '73\xa0F', '72\xa0F', '96\xa0%', 'SW', '9\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.35\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '12:30 AM', '73\xa0F', '71\xa0F', '95\xa0%', 'WSW', '9\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.35\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '3:30 AM', '74\xa0F', '73\xa0F', '95\xa0%', 'SE', '6\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.39\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Mostly Cloudy', '5:30 AM', '78\xa0F', '76\xa0F', '92\xa0%', 'SW', '7\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.40\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '8:30 AM', '79\xa0F', '75\xa0F', '87\xa0%', 'SW', '9\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.34\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Mostly Cloudy', '11:30 AM', '77\xa0F', '75\xa0F', '93\xa0%', 'SW', '6\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.33\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '2:30 PM', '76\xa0F', '75\xa0F', '96\xa0%', 'SW', '3\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.38\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Mostly Cloudy', '5:30 PM', '76\xa0F', '74\xa0F', '95\xa0%', 'SW', '7\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.41\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Mostly Cloudy', '8:30 PM', '73\xa0F', '72\xa0F', '96\xa0%', 'SW', '9\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.35\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '12:30 AM', '73\xa0F', '71\xa0F', '95\xa0%', 'WSW', '9\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.35\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Cloudy', '3:30 AM', '74\xa0F', '73\xa0F', '95\xa0%', 'SE', '6\xa0mph', '0\xa0mph', '29.39\xa0in', '0.0\xa0in', 'Mostly Cloudy']
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace`:

```py
stmat.append(cell.text.replace("\xa0",""))
```

However, your code could use some cleanup. You don't need to create a single list for all the cells, just use a 2D list.

```py
rows = []
for row in stat_table.find_all("tr"):
    cells = (
        row.find(class_="cdk-column-temperature"), 
        row.find(class_="cdk-column-dewPoint"),
        row.find(class_="cdk-column-humidity"),
        row.find(class_="cdk-column-windSpeed"),
        row.find(class_="cdk-column-windGust")
    )
    rows.append([cell.text.replace("\xa0","") for cell in cells]
```

Comment: I need the array to create a matrix, and the from that matrix I have to extract columns and calculate average and stuff

Comment: also is there a way to amend just the numbers from the string into the array

Comment: What about the non numerical cells?

Comment: I won't be considering them anyway so i just want the ones with F % MPH and in
and i wont be considering the time and cloudy stuff

Comment: Can you post the website url?

Comment: https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/in/mangalore/VOML/date/2012-8-31

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be unicode data you should be normalizing it per `NFKC` standards. That is because the `\xa0` character represents a non-breaking space. We can see this when we do `chr(160)` which returns `'\xa0'`.

```
import unicodedata

stmat.append(unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", cell.text))
```